# Does climate change generate more cold waves?

Tags: climate-change, climatology

I answered to this question some time ago:

[Who are winners from the global warming? Are there any?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/21136/who-are-winners-from-the-global-warming-are-there-any/24488#24488)

The user asked if Russia would benefit from climate change.

I found a paper that asserts:

> Our simulations with the ECHAM5 general circulation model demonstrate that lower‐troposphere heating over the B‐K seas in the Eastern Arctic caused by the sea ice reduction may result in strong anticyclonic anomaly over the Polar Ocean and anomalous easterly advection over northern continents. This causes a continental‐scale winter cooling reaching −1.5°C, with more than 3 times increased probability of cold winter extremes over large areas including Europe. **Our results imply that several recent severe winters do not conflict the global warming picture but rather supplement it**.
>
> **Source**: [A link between reduced Barents‐Kara sea ice and cold winter extremes over northern continents", *Climate and Dynamics*](https://doi.org/10.1029/2009JD013568), cited in [Expect more extreme winters thanks to Global Warming, say scientists, Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/climate-change/news/expect-more-extreme-winters-thanks-to-global-warming-say-scientists-2168418.html).

The paper only mentions large areas of the Northern Hemisphere including Europe, but the current cold wave in United States makes me wonder if this is something global and also affecting the Southern Hemisphere.

I am sure climate change make the winters shorter, but are those short winters more extreme?

Is this something global or only regional because of the anticyclonic anomaly over the Polar Ocean?

Comment: Climate change makes summers more extreme and makes autumn, winter, and spring more variable. Winter is when the temperature variation between the pole and the equator is at its greatest.

Comment: This is likely to be an extreme localized weather event, not a persistent climatic trend. South eastern Australia recently had two less extreme versions. It's now summer in the southern hemisphere & in November & mid December two brief periods cold snaps occurred where the temperatures were up the 12 C below average. Snow fell down to 500m in some parts. [*Cold snap sends shivers through south-east while north swelters waiting for monsoon*](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-11-21/cold-snap-south-east-while-north-swelters/101678454) &  ...

Comment: [*Pre-Christmas cold spell delivers snow and near-record-low summer temperatures*](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-12-14/cold-spell-ahead-of-christmas-in-australia/101768210). As unusual as this is, it has occurred previously. Snow falling on Christmas day has occurred in the southern parts of Tasmania, but it is a very rare event. It's just a localized aberration as a result of a conjunction of El Nina, a negative Indian Ocean Dipole combined & a [Southern Annual Mode (SAM)](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/sam/).